# convert bind variable to a nested table

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012

Is there any way to convert bind variable to nested table in MS SQL Server. Something like [CAST](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions016.htm) in Oracle which converts a varray type column into a nested table?
In Oracle we can write such a code:

```
SELECT CAST(s.addresses AS address_book_t)
   FROM states s 
   WHERE s.state_id = 111;
```

What is the same function in MS SQL Server?

Comment: There are no nested tables in SQL Server, you should use a separate table with a 1-many relation to `states`. There are xml types and in the 2016 version, Json but they aren't as easy to use as a Join. Even in Oracle, it can be argued that if you want to search on something, it should be in a separate table

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a direct correlation.

Your best bet would be to pass s.Addresses into a CTE or Subquery and parsing it in there.

However without having any knowledge of the structures involved it's kinda hard to provide any workable example.